# Twilio REST API Conference Select participants to listen to

Tags: twilio, twilio-conference

Is it possible to select which participants to listen in a conference as a moderator?
In other words just mute a participant for the moderator not for all the other participants.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The short answer is: no.

The slightly longer answer is:

Conference calls are all mixed together on a media server, not shared peer to peer. If one user is muted, they are muted for everyone as they are muted at that stage.